# How to get fully qualified name for user defined datatype in Custom Java Sonar rule

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonarlint

Please find below code snippet.

```
    Public class UserDefinedDTO {

    // userDefined variable is refers to UserDefined class
    private UserDefined userDefined;

    private String name;

    }

@Rule(key = "UserDefinedChecks", name = "Java Doc check", description = "", priority = Priority.BLOCKER, tags = {
        "bug" })
public class UserDefinedChecks extends IssuableSubscriptionVisitor{

    @Override
    public List<Kind> nodesToVisit() {
        return ImmutableList.of(Kind.VARIABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void visitNode(Tree tree) {
        VariableTree variable = (VariableTree) tree;
        String name = variable.type().symbolType().fullyQualifiedName();
        System.out.println(name);
     }
}
```

Output :

```
java.lang.String
!unknownSymbol!
```

while fetching the fullyQualifiedName for user Defined data type it gives !unknownSymbol! instead of exact qualified name but if I used String instead of user defined data type then it gives java.lang.String

Kindly let me know how to fetch fully qualified name for user defined data type. Appreciate for your help.

Answer (score 0):

That means you haven't imported UserDefined class properly. Add import